# CSS: move an element, overriding its position in the HTML

Tags: css

Let's say I have this HTML page:

```
<body>
<p id="alice">Alice</p>
<p id="bob">Bob</p>
</body>
```

and this pretend CSS syntax:

```
p#alice:before { p#bob }
```

In other words, I want to override the HTML using CSS, placing the Bob element ABOVE the Alice element.  Why?  Because in my case I can edit the CSS, and I cannot edit the HTML.

Bob doesn't have to actually occur before Alice in the DOM, but it does need to appear ABOVE Alice visually.

Comment: If you know the height of `#bob` you could just position `#alice` absolutely,with a top distance of `#bob`'s height.

Comment: You have ways in CSS to show Bob above Alice without changing the HTML flow, what's the current CSS?

Comment: You *could* fix this with absolute or relative positioning...but *if* you can edit/add JavaScript then that would be a much better solution.

Comment: No, I can only edit CSS in this case.  And I'm not going to use absolute positioning under any circumstances -- it has to be relative.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to do this with pure CSS that is completely flexible is with flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9L3r/ (prefixes not included)

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

#alice {
    order: 2;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this with jQuery if you are able to add the code.

```
$('#bob').insertBefore('#alice');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy but ugly and you shouldnt do it.

However here is how to do it:

http://jsbin.com/azevet/2/edit

```
<div class="first-in-dom">
  Im first in DOM
  </div>
<div class="second-in-dom">
  Im second in DOM
  </div>


div {
  height:100px;
  border:solid;
}
.first-in-dom, .second-in-dom {
  position:relative;
}
.first-in-dom {
  margin-bottom:-100px;
    top:110px;

}
```

Comment: +1 Vote This would probably be your best option if you cannot use jQuery.